# Merge PageViewer fragments on rotation from vertical to horizontal

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm working on an android application that displays two images in separate fragments using PageViewer. I was wondering how I can possibly merge the two fragments into the same screen, or place them side by side on a rotation of the screen. It would be similar to the first image below, expect it would be due to page rotation, and not device type:

[Building a Flexible UI](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

Ideally, I could merge the two images onto one fragment if they fit. Should this be done using an if statement? The code I'm using is very similar to the android screen slide demo:

**Main Activity:**

```
package com.example.android.animationsdemo;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

/**
 * Demonstrates a "screen-slide" animation using a {@link ViewPager}. Because {@link ViewPager}
 * automatically plays such an animation when calling {@link ViewPager#setCurrentItem(int)}, there
 * isn't any animation-specific code in this sample.
 *
 * <p>This sample shows a "next" button that advances the user to the next step in a wizard,
 * animating the current screen out (to the left) and the next screen in (from the right). The
 * reverse animation is played when the user presses the "previous" button.</p>
 *
 * @see ScreenSlidePageFragment
 */
public class ScreenSlideActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /**
     * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
     */
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;

    /**
     * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
     * and next wizard steps.
     */
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // When changing pages, reset the action bar actions since they are dependent
                // on which page is currently active. An alternative approach is to have each
                // fragment expose actions itself (rather than the activity exposing actions),
                // but for simplicity, the activity provides the actions in this sample.
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_screen_slide, menu);

        menu.findItem(R.id.action_previous).setEnabled(mPager.getCurrentItem() > 0);

        // Add either a "next" or "finish" button to the action bar, depending on which page
        // is currently selected.
        MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.action_next, Menu.NONE,
                (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1)
                        ? R.string.action_finish
                        : R.string.action_next);
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // Navigate "up" the demo structure to the launchpad activity.
                // See http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html for more.
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                return true;

            case R.id.action_previous:
                // Go to the previous step in the wizard. If there is no previous step,
                // setCurrentItem will do nothing.
                mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
                return true;

            case R.id.action_next:
                // Advance to the next step in the wizard. If there is no next step, setCurrentItem
                // will do nothing.
                mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 {@link ScreenSlidePageFragment} objects, in
     * sequence.
     */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
}
```

**ScreenSlideFragment**

```
package com.example.android.animationsdemo;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A fragment representing a single step in a wizard. The fragment shows a dummy title indicating
 * the page number, along with some dummy text.
 *
 * <p>This class is used by the {@link CardFlipActivity} and {@link
 * ScreenSlideActivity} samples.</p>
 */
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The argument key for the page number this fragment represents.
     */
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";

    /**
     * The fragment's page number, which is set to the argument value for {@link #ARG_PAGE}.
     */
    private int mPageNumber;

    /**
     * Factory method for this fragment class. Constructs a new fragment for the given page number.
     */
    public static ScreenSlidePageFragment create(int pageNumber) {
        ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ScreenSlidePageFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

        // Set the title view to show the page number.
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
                getString(R.string.title_template_step, mPageNumber + 1));

        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the page number represented by this fragment object.
     */
    public int getPageNumber() {
        return mPageNumber;
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You have a ViewPager

2) You set adapter for ViewPager

```
public class ImageFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    ArrayList<String> images;
    public ImageFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> images) {
        super(fm);
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        ImageFragment fragment = new ImageFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("image_url", images.get(position));
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }
}
```

3) Each fragment is a image

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment{
View view;
ImageView ivImage;
Bundle bundle;
String imageUrl;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, null);
    ivImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivImageAlbum);
    bundle = getArguments();
    if(bundle != null){
        imageUrl = bundle.getString("image_url");
        try{
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrl, ivImage, ImageLoadOption.options);
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    return view;
}
```

4) Using the ImageLoader or Picaso Image Lib to show image
I hope it will help you